# ImageIO.read() returns null

Tags: java, imageurl

I have a problem regarding the ImageIO.read() function:

```
URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource(sheetPath);
spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
```

The ImageIO function returns null even though the URL is correct (it leads to a .png file).
I've tried to put the getResource() as a parameter for the read function, but that didn't work either. Has anyone encountered a similar problem and maybe found a solution?

Regards

**Edit:**

sheetPath is "/images/pizzaGirl.png"

imageURL is "file:/Users/Kevin/Dropbox/workspace/PizzaGirl/bin/images/pizzaGirl.png"

images is in the "res" folder which I added to the classpath via the eclipse's run configurations

Comment: `"The ImageIO function returns null **even though the URL is correct** (it leads to a .png file)."` -- when you encounter an error like you're seeing, it would be wise not to assume anything, especially this assumption. In all likelihood, you're not in fact using the correct path to the resource. No way for us to know though based on what you're posting. Show your sheetPath String, and show us where the image is located relative to your class files.

Comment: Is `ImageIO.read()` throwing its `IOException`?

Comment: Also, have you debugged to check that `imageURL` is non-null?

Comment: So is the images directory in fact a sub-directory off of the bin directory?

Comment: Have you actually looked in the `bin` dir to see that `images` is there?

Comment: updated the question, and @peeskillet : yea its in there

Comment: Try this. Go to the build configuration by right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Source Tab -> Add Folder -> add res. Then run it. See what happens

Comment: If that doesn't work, post a simple runnable example that we can run. that demonstrates the problem. Might be a problem with something else

Comment: @peeskillet the folder is already added, and i've already showed you the two relevant lines of code here, what else shall i provide?

Comment: A runnable example. If I have  a project with res/images in the root. Then do the my previous comment. Then use the path `/images/image.png`, It never fails. That's why I say post a runnable example that demonstrates the problem. Beside, the code above, if the path is wrong it will throw an IllegalArgumentException. That said, there's not enough information from two lines of code to possible help debug a NullPointerException. It could be any number of things. None of which is caused by those two lines of code. Also whenever you get an exception, post the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I tried to replace my path with a different image and it worked. I went back into photoshop, exported my image again and voilà, it works.

Comment: ImageIO.read(imageURL);  
supports only the following image formats :
bmp, jpeg, wbmp, gif, png, JPG, jpg, WBMP, JPEG

Any others will be returned as null (Verify the content type of the image).

Answer (score -1):

Check if the path is really correct. To do this write:

`System.out.println(new File(yourPathHere).exists());`

then if it returns false please post the path. I will check if it is correct.

Comment: This will check the File path not the resource path, two completely different paths.